# Xcode Project doesn't Archive after Ventura and Xcode update

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Hello i am going crazy because i am trying to Archive my Project to update my app but i cant. It all started after i updated my macbook with Ventura and Xcode. This is the error i am getting

```
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cpkczvqkllwmbxfgqfjerveeovoc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/Rovespier.build/Script-EA548DA28679960CB6901F80.sh (in target 'Rovespier' from project 'App')
    cd /Users/macuser/Desktop/Rovespiere-capacitor/ios/App
    /bin/sh -c /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cpkczvqkllwmbxfgqfjerveeovoc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/Rovespier.build/Script-EA548DA28679960CB6901F80.sh

mkdir -p /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cpkczvqkllwmbxfgqfjerveeovoc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Rovespier.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AppAuth.framework" "/Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cpkczvqkllwmbxfgqfjerveeovoc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Rovespier.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/macuser/Desktop/Rovespiere-capacitor/ios/App/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AppAuth.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/97f6331a-ba75-11ed-a4bc-863efbbaf80d/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

1. I have deleted DeliveredData inside Library/Developer/Xcode/DeliveredData
2. The App.Auth exists in the Pods directory
3. App.Auth is in Build Settings/Search Paths/Framework Search paths

   ```
   //:configuration = Release
    FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) 
    "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppAuth" 
    "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Capacitor" 
    ........
    //:completeSettings = none
   ```

Xcode gave me an option to use the version 1. From Xcode or 2 Read from disk and i pressed Use the one from Xcode if that matters. It runs and builds just fine dont i cannot Archive. Any help?

Comment: Hey there, I am countering the same error from couple of days and yet to find any proper solution for thus. Please let me know if you find any solution for above.